# Is there any way to accept keyboard input without having the window in focus

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard

I am using the pygame module in python to make display applications for my youtube/personal use. I can get input from my keyboard when I have the Pygame window in focus, but not when I am using another application.
Is there:

1. Some way to accept inputs while unfocused in pygame?
2. Some other module I can import to receive inputs while unfocused?

Answer (score 1):

One module that comes to mind is [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/), although I would check out the known limitations on its README from its [github](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) to see if it's really right for your use case.