# How to make my Pygame window always active and listening for input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I spent the last 3 hours searching for a way to create a simple toggle button script that lets me know if a button on my Thrustmaster HOTAS has been pressed. As I am a bloody beginner I didn't write this code myself. I found one that suits my means and configured it to my liking.

Now I want this script to be active and running when I am ingame. Preferably also on top of other windows. Because it doesn't recognize the inputs if the window isn't active.

[Bring a pygame window to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69666786/bring-a-pygame-window-to-front?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to make python window run as "Always On Top"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482565/how-to-make-python-window-run-as-always-on-top?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Pygame set window on top without changing its position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381589/pygame-set-window-on-top-without-changing-its-position?noredirect=1&lq=1)

These were the most promising ones I found beside many others. Tried all of them even though the second one is for linux.

[pygame capture keyboard events when window not in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380938/pygame-capture-keyboard-events-when-window-not-in-focus)

Also found this one, but they explain how to hook Keyboard inputs, not Joystick inputs.

I am using Win10 and the newest python version.

**Update:** I added these lines and now the window stays on top all the time but it's still not always active.

```py
import win32gui
import win32con

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd,win32con.HWND_TOPMOST,100,100,200,200,0)
```

That's the whole script I am using

```
import sys
import pygame

import win32gui
import win32con

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('ToggleCheck')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((180, 110), 0, 32)
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd,win32con.HWND_TOPMOST,100,100,200,200,0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=44100, size=32, channels=2, buffer=4096)
pygame.joystick.init()
joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
for joystick in joysticks:
    print(joystick.get_name())

my_square = pygame.Rect(30, 30, 50, 50)
my_square2 = pygame.Rect(100, 30, 50, 50)
my_square_color = 0
my_square_color2 = 0
colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0)]
motion = [0, 0]

while True:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors[my_square_color], my_square)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors[my_square_color2], my_square2)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print(event)
            if event.button == 8:
                if (my_square_color % 2) == 0:
                    my_square_color = (my_square_color + 1) % len(colors)
                    on = pygame.mixer.Sound("Desktop\DCS\checker\sounds\on.wav")
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(on)
                else:
                    my_square_color = (my_square_color + 1) % len(colors)
                    on = pygame.mixer.Sound("Desktop\DCS\checker\sounds\off.wav")
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(on)
        if event.type == JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print(event)
            if event.button == 9:
                if (my_square_color2 % 2) == 0:
                    my_square_color2 = (my_square_color2 + 1) % len(colors)
                    on = pygame.mixer.Sound("Desktop\DCS\checker\sounds\on.wav")
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(on)
                else:
                    my_square_color2 = (my_square_color2 + 1) % len(colors)
                    on = pygame.mixer.Sound("Desktop\DCS\checker\sounds\off.wav")
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(on)
        if event.type == JOYDEVICEADDED:
            joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
            for joystick in joysticks:
                print(joystick.get_name())
        if event.type == JOYDEVICEREMOVED:
            joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here but you've got two 'if' statements checking if event.type == JOYBUTTONDOWN, nothing checking if the button has been released.

Comment: @Linden I just want to script to do stuff when the buttons are pressed. I don't really care about something happening when I release the buttons. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Will this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898640/is-there-any-way-to-accept-keyboard-input-without-having-the-window-in-focus

Comment: Will this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898640/is-there-any-way-to-accept-keyboard-input-without-having-the-window-in-focus

Answer (score 0):

Try using this py-joystick module
https://pypi.org/project/pyjoystick/

```
from pyjoystick.sdl2 import Key, Joystick, run_event_loop

def print_add(joy):
    print('Added', joy)

def print_remove(joy):
    print('Removed', joy)

def key_received(key):
    print('received', key)
    if key.value == Key.HAT_UP:
        #do something
    elif key.value == Key.HAT_DOWN:
        #do something
    if key.value == Key.HAT_LEFT:
        #do something
    elif key.value == Key.HAT_UPLEFT:
        #do something
    elif key.value == Key.HAT_DOWNLEFT:
        #do something
    elif key.value == Key.HAT_RIGHT:
        #do something
    elif key.value == Key.HAT_UPRIGHT:
        #do something
    elif key.value == Key.HAT_DOWNRIGHT:
        #do something

run_event_loop(print_add, print_remove, key_received)
```